# Getting Error: wrong pg_constraint entry for trigger

Tags: postgresql

I have not been able to find any details on this error at all.  Specifically, I'm running a query similar to:

```
UPDATE "data"."campaigns" SET "name"='New Name' WHERE ("id"='182')
```

... and I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  wrong pg_constraint entry for trigger "RI_ConstraintTrigger_54145"
        on table "campaigns"
```

If it helps, here is the definition for the trigger:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER
   "RI_ConstraintTrigger_54145"
AFTER UPDATE ON
   "data"."campaigns"
FROM
   "data"."ethics_wall_exemptions"
NOT DEFERRABLE
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE
   "RI_FKey_noaction_upd"();
```

Also, the query works fine on the DEV database; the error only throws on the production database.  I've not been able to find any differences, but I'm sure something is different.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just noticed that `INSERT` a new campaign is possible, but `UPDATE` campaign is not.

Comment: Try to drop and recreate the trigger.  BTW, why is `id` matched against a string, which contains a number?

Answer (score 0):

Check the foreign key constraint definition:

```
SELECT conname, conrelid::regclass, confrelid::regclass, confupdtype, confdeltype
FROM pg_constraint
WHERE conname = 'RI_ConstraintTrigger_54145';
```

then can proceed with dropping and recreating the trigger "RI_ConstraintTrigger_54145" in the production database.

```
-- Drop the trigger
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS "RI_ConstraintTrigger_54145" ON "data"."campaigns";

-- Recreate the trigger
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER "RI_ConstraintTrigger_54145"
AFTER UPDATE ON "data"."campaigns"
FROM "data"."ethics_wall_exemptions"
NOT DEFERRABLE
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE "RI_FKey_noaction_upd"();
```